# Why does timeit report slower code as faster one?

Tags: python, timeit, debian-stretch

I tested this with python 3.5 in Debian Stretch.
I tried benchmark [the "Avoiding dots" optimization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...).
As expected, [the "Avoiding dots" optimization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) is really much faster.
Unexpected, timeit reports the slower code as the faster.
What is the reason?

```
$ time python3 -m timeit -s "s=''" "s.isalpha()"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.119 usec per loop

real    0m5.023s
user    0m4.922s
sys 0m0.012s
$ time python3 -m timeit -s "isalpha=str.isalpha;s=''" "isalpha(s)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.212 usec per loop

real    0m0.937s
user    0m0.927s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: This is to be expected in this case: `isalpha(s)` does the same amount of work as `s.isalpha()`, as you can verify when inspecting the bytecode. It's only when you can avoid an entire operation that "avoiding dots" helps. Here you trade off an argument for an attribute lookup.

Comment: In other words, `timeit` does not lie. If it says something is not faster, then it is not faster ;)

Comment: @zvone. Unless it's your first run sometimes

Comment: @L3viathan If they do the same amount of work, then why is one almost twice as fast as the other?

Comment: What happens when you force the same number of loops with `-n 10000000`? And are the times stable, i.e., if you run it multiple times, do you always get roughly the same results?

Comment: The “avoiding dots” optimization here should be `s=''; f=s.isalpha` and then `f()`, which is in fact twice as fast in my test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeit` did 10 times as many **iterations** in the “slow” case.  It adaptively tries more iterations to find a number that balances statistical quality and waiting time.

Comment: This is a valid, and even valuable observation, but doesn't explain why one time is unexpectedly less than the other.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The question as stated is why `timeit` disagrees with the questioner’s expectations (which were apparently set by `time` “confirming” a theory about optimization).  This answers that, not the underlying question about why one version of the code is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [Davis Herring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414389/9377221).
Let's make understand at more details:
From `python3 -m timeit -h`:

```
If -n is not given, a suitable number of loops is calculated by trying
successive powers of 10 until the total time is at least 0.2 seconds.
```

Verify by calculate the details information:

```
$ time python3 -m timeit -v -s "s=''" "s.isalpha()"
10 loops -> 3.44e-06 secs
100 loops -> 1.29e-05 secs
1000 loops -> 0.000117 secs
10000 loops -> 0.00116 secs
100000 loops -> 0.0118 secs
1000000 loops -> 0.116 secs
10000000 loops -> 1.17 secs
raw times: 1.21 1.21 1.21
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.121 usec per loop

real    0m4.992s
user    0m4.977s
sys 0m0.012s
```

All the `x loops -> y secs` time sum is used to determine the suitable loops number.
Each items in the "raw time" line are single repeat timer result([the `-r` option](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html#cmdoption-timeit-r) determine the number of items in the "raw time" line).
Almost all time is matched:

```
>>> 3.44e-06+1.29e-05+0.000117+0.00116+0.0118+0.116+1.17+1.21+1.21+1.21
4.92909334
>>> 4.992-4.92909334
0.06290666000000034
```